# How to import variables stored in a python file in a different directory?

Tags: python, subdirectory

My folder structure looks like the following:

[image: Folder structure looks like this]

**Backend/config.py**
`hostName = "0.0.0.0"`

**Backend/Utils/upload.py**
`#I want to use the hostName in this file, how to import it?`

I tried using the following in the upload file:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import config as appConf
```

If I execute my program from the folder Backend:

```
\Backend> py .\utils\upload.py
```

it is working fine. But if I keep it as

```
\Backend\Utils> py upload.py
```

it is not working. I would like to understand how this works. I am trying to execute this from my python virtual environment.

Kindly help me out.

I am sorry if my question is not clear or very simple.

Comment: You can always use the `os` module to change the current directory (`os.chdir(path)`), though there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your varriable in

> class

then import your upload.py file into the desired file and get.
e.g.

> `Upload.hostName`

Answer (score 0):

`\Backend> py .\utils\upload.py` - Here, there is a 'utils' folder. And you said it is working fine.

`\Backend\Utils> py upload.py` - Here, it is 'Utils'. Could you please clarify on this ?

Comment: I mean if I keep the directory name till Backend in the terminal and try executing the command, it is working fine. But If I change the directory till Utils and try executing with `´py upload.py` command it is not working.

Comment: Can you show what error are you getting on executing `py upload.py` ?

Comment: I tried changing the upload file content as follows

```import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import Backend.config as appConf```

I got the result as 

``import Backend.config as appConf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Backend'``

Comment: I don't want the code to be dependent on the terminal folder structure, irrespective of the folder I am there in the terminal, I want my code to be executed. How can I possibly do that?